# MemoryError using modred

Tags: python

Anybody has face this problem when using the [modred](http://pythonhosted.org/modred/) library? I got MemoryError when using the ERA method with an array of size N= 120000. (I already check my memory usage, up to 4GB of free RAM at this point, and I also check my code to see that I work with my objects properly)

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same problem, with an array of size N = 5.000.000. Maybe you can remove the memory at the end ?
Are you looping in your array ?

Comment: Hi @Andromedae93, yeah, it happened before with an array of about 1.000.000 samples also. The looping is performed by the modred.era, the stack error points at that function, before and after... there are loops for loading and saving data, but I have check those pieces of code already. We will have to make a closer look at this function.